# Maximum in a group of straight lines

Tags: geometry

Suppose you have n straight lines , of form `ax+b`.

Is there any direct method to find the max value this group of straight lines at a particular value of $x$?

e.g. For $n = 2$,we have two lines $2x + 3$ and $5x - 6$

For $x = 2$ , we have $y = 7$ as $2x+3$ attains the value of $7$.

For $x = 10$, we have $y = 44$ as $5x-6$ attains the value of $44$.

Is there any way I can find just the maximum of $n$ straight lines , without having to calculate individual values of each straight line for a given value of $x$?

Comment: This depends on context. If you have many lines but you will just need to find the value of the greatest $y$ for a given value of $x$ a few times, then the most efficient calculation may just be to compute each $y$ value at a given $x$ value and take the largest. The alternative is to do a lot of work to figure out a single function describing the greatest $y$ at each $x$, and even then the function can be much more expensive to evaluate than a single line's function is. If you explained why you are looking for a "direct method", you might get better answers.

Comment: For example, do you have some practical problem you need to solve relative to a specific set of equations, do you need to solve this more generally for a piece of software your company is making, or is this an exercise for school or university (and if so, how much detail is the question looking for--just that a "direct" method exists, or actually showing how to develop the method, or an asymptotic complexity analysis)?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Solve linear equations to find all the points where two lines intersect.

(2) Between each pair of adjacent crossings, as well as before the first and after the last, find which line has the largest value.

(Solution) When given a value, find which range it is in first before finding the value.

(Optimization) If there are very many lines a binary search algorithm can be used to find the proper range. Points across which the top two lines do not intersect can be removed from the list. Part (1) can also probably be optimized to obviate unnecessary algebra.

(Analysis)
Step (1) takes quadratic time and step (2) takes cubic time, however after those steps are finished, each evaluation takes at most logarithmic time.